# Passing generics and have to cast into correct object java. should not have to cast

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm trying to implement a method so I do not have to cast the parameter with java generics.

Here is a call I make.

```
new NetworkAsyncTask(new NetworkCall("http://192.168.1.107/api/api/index.php/api/item/524a1e7c3a5d9", HttpMethod.GET, null, new Item()), this).execute();
```

Then the NetworkAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask.
In this class there is an onPostExecute method that does a call back to the original class that instantiated NetworkAsyncTask

```
    protected void onPostExecute(T response) {         
        networkCallback.postExecute(response);         
    }
```

The class that instantiated NetworkAsyncTask gets the call back.  (this is where the problem lies.)

```
    public <T> void postExecute(T response) {
        Item item = (Item) response;;
    }
```

The object response is a java generic correct?  Therefore, I shouldn't have to cast it.  The code should like

```
    public <T> void postExecute(T response) {
        Item item =  response;
    }
```

How do I accomplish this? Is it possible?

Comment: Please post actual code that demonstrates your issue. As it is, it's unclear what you're asking. What's the "original class" that is overriding `postExecute()` and what is it extending?

Comment: if your `postExecute` method is declared like that, it might as well be declared as `public void postExecute(Object response)`. There is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

if your T extends Item than you dont have to cast,

```
public <T extends Item> void postExecute(T response) {
        Item item =  response;
}
```

Comment: this makes sense because item becomes the parent of T but I do not want to extend anything.  I want to use java generics so T can be anything.  So the method can get any object back an not have to cast it.  Example)
public <T> void postExecute(T response) {
        Soda item =  response;
}
Is my original question not clear enough?

Comment: because of type erasure you will not get the type desired.you have to cast it.

Comment: might as well declare it as `public void postExecute(Item response)` then

Comment: @raging_subs you seem to be confused as to what Generics are. How do you suppose "anything" you pass into that method is going to magically become or be able to be cast to a `Soda` (or `Item` as in your original example) ? `T` is a specific type (in this case inferred from what is being passed in), not "anything". In the end, all Generics really are in Java is some compile time type checking.

Comment: @BrianRoach I agree with you.